# Converting my JQuery function to vanilla js - Issue with multiple forEach?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have noticed that converting a JQuery function takes more code to convert in vanilla JS.

I am trying to convert the following code:

```
$('.tabs__toggle').click(function () {
    $('.tabs__single').removeClass('tabs__single--active');
    $(".tabs__single[data-id='" + $(this).attr('data-id') + "']").addClass(
        'tabs__single--active'
    );
    $('.tabs__toggle').removeClass('tabs__toggle--active');
    $(this).parent().find('.tabs__toggle').addClass('tabs__toggle--active');
});
```

By default, you don't need to use a `forEach` click on JQuery to add a click event.

This is my code trying to convert:

```
const Toggles = tabs.querySelectorAll('.tabs__toggle');

const onToggleClick = (toggle) => {
    $('.tabs__single').removeClass('tabs__single--active');
    $(".tabs__single[data-id='" + $(this).attr('data-id') + "']").addClass(
        'tabs__single--active'
    );
};

Toggles.forEach((toggle) => {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', onToggleClick.bind(null, toggle));
});
```

But I am stuck with the `"tabs__single"` I have to add a `forEach` inside a `ForEach`.

HTML:

```
<div data-rel="tabs" class="tabs">
    <aside class="tabs__sidebar">
        <h3 class="tabs__pretitle">Filter op:</h3>
        <ul class="tabs__menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="tabs__toggle" data-id="department-fashion">Fashion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="tabs__toggle" data-id="department-lifestyle">Lifestyle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="tabs__toggle" data-id="department-gifts">Gifts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="tabs__toggle" data-id="department-horeca">Horeca</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <div class="tabs__single" data-id="department-fashion">
        <h2>Fashion</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="tabs__single" data-id="department-lifestyle">
        <h2>Lifestyle</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="tabs__single" data-id="department-gifts">
        <h2>Gifts</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="tabs__single" data-id="department-horeca">
        <h2>Horeca</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me out to convert this?

Comment: I sure hope it takes more code since there are tons of lines of code in the jQuery core. :)

Comment: JQuery - framework. It wraps some extra JS code for you in the background

Comment: I have no clue why you are doing `$(this).parent().find('.tabs__toggle')` Are you just selecting the element you already have? Hard to guess with out HTML

Comment: @epascarello updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do indeed need another `forEach()` within the event handler to loop over the `.tabs__single` collection. This is something jQuery does for you and which you'll need to do manually in native JS.

The code will end up looking something like the following. Note the use of the `Event` object in the `onToggleClick` function arguments instead of unnecessarily binding to the `toggle` instance. This pattern is built in to JS and is far more prevalent and easy to work with.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs');
const toggles = tabs.querySelectorAll('.tabs__toggle');
const tabsContent = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs__single');

const onToggleClick = e => {
  // set class on active tab
  let activeTab = document.querySelector('.tabs__toggle.tabs__toggle--active');
  activeTab && activeTab.classList.remove('tabs__toggle--active');
  e.target.classList.add('tabs__toggle--active');
  
  // display active tab content
  let targetId = e.target.dataset.id;
  tabsContent.forEach(el => {
    el.classList[el.dataset.id === targetId ? 'add' : 'remove']('tabs__single--active');
  });
};

toggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', onToggleClick);
});
```

```css
.tabs__single { display: none; }
.tabs__single--active { display: block; }
.tabs__toggle--active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<div data-rel="tabs" class="tabs">
  <aside class="tabs__sidebar">
    <h3 class="tabs__pretitle">Filter op:</h3>
    <ul class="tabs__menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="tabs__toggle" data-id="department-fashion">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tabs__toggle" data-id="department-lifestyle">Lifestyle</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tabs__toggle" data-id="department-gifts">Gifts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tabs__toggle" data-id="department-horeca">Horeca</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>

  <div class="tabs__single" data-id="department-fashion">
    <h2>Fashion</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs__single" data-id="department-lifestyle">
    <h2>Lifestyle</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs__single" data-id="department-gifts">
    <h2>Gifts</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs__single" data-id="department-horeca">
    <h2>Horeca</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All that changed is the HTML? The JS appears to be the same. I've updated the answer anyway.

Comment: thanks! Only the tabs__toggle is not being set to active on click

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that part. Answer updated

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Just a forEach with querySelector all and using classList

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs__toggle').forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.tabs__single--active').forEach(selected => {
      selected.classList.remove('tabs__single--active');
    });
    var selectedToggle = document.querySelector('.tabs__toggle--active');
    if (selectedToggle) selectedToggle.classList.remove('tabs__toggle--active');

    var id = elem.dataset.id;
    document.querySelectorAll(`.tabs__single[data-id='${id}']`).forEach(selected => {
      selected.classList.add('tabs__single--active');
    });

    elem.classList.add('tabs__toggle--active');

  });
});
```

```css
.tabs__toggle--active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.tabs__single--active {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs__toggle" data-id="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="tabs__toggle" data-id="bar">Bar</div>


<div class="tabs__single" data-id="foo">Foo 1</div>
<div class="tabs__single" data-id="foo">Foo 2</div>
<div class="tabs__single" data-id="foo">Foo 3</div>

<div class="tabs__single" data-id="bar">Bar 1</div>
<div class="tabs__single" data-id="bar">Bar 2</div>
<div class="tabs__single" data-id="bar">Bar 3</div>
```

If it is just a single element for single active no need for forEach

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs__toggle').forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    const selected = document.querySelector('.tabs__single--active');
    if (selected) selected.classList.remove('tabs__single--active');
    const selectedToggle = document.querySelector('.tabs__toggle--active');
    if (selectedToggle) selectedToggle.classList.remove('tabs__toggle--active');

    const id = elem.dataset.id;
    document.querySelector(`.tabs__single[data-id='${id}']`).classList.add('tabs__single--active');


    elem.classList.add('tabs__toggle--active');

  });
});
```

```css
.tabs__toggle--active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.tabs__single--active {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs__toggle" data-id="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="tabs__toggle" data-id="bar">Bar</div>


<div class="tabs__single" data-id="foo">Foo 1</div>

<div class="tabs__single" data-id="bar">Bar 1</div>
```